# CustomUser matching query does not exist. ERROR( DJANGO)

Tags: python, django, forms, web, view

when i save the form in template.
The error says:

> CustomUser matching query does not exist.
>
> Line number 104: teacher=CustomUser.objects.get(id=teachers_id)

Model.py

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course_id=models.ForeignKey(Courses,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    teachers_id=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
def add_subject_save(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
    else:
        subject_name=request.POST.get("subject_name")
        course_id=request.POST.get("course")
        course=Courses.objects.get(id=course_id)
        teachers_id=request.POST.get("teacher")
        teacher=CustomUser.objects.get(id=teachers_id)

        try:
            subject=Subjects(subject_name=subject_name,course_id=course,teachers_id=teacher)
            subject.save()
            messages.success(request,"Successfully Added Subject")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("add_subject")
        except:
            messages.error(request,"Failed to Add Subject")
            return HttpResponseRedirec("add_subject")
```

I dont know how to solve this error.

Comment: Just check manually using `python manage.py shell` if the teacher_id that you are passing through post request exits or not

Comment: kindly tell me, how do i do that?

Comment: just run the above command and and import model from `<app_name>.model ` and just `teacher=CustomUser.objects.get(id=teachers_id)`replace teacher id with the value that you are passing through the post method

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the Django ForeignKeys stores an object, not an integer like you would use in SQL. I think `teacher=CustomUser.objects.get(id=teachers_id)` is the bandit here. I would try `teacher=CustomUser.objects.filter(teacher_id__exact=teacher_id).get()`. This will give you an error however if there are more than one objects in the CustomUser model with the same teacher object. There is more information about this on the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter).